# Mathematical definition of the variable importance measure 'increase in node purity' from R randomForests package?

Tags: r, random-forest, cart, importance

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of variable importance (for regression) from the `randomForest` package in R. I'm trying to find a mathematical definition of how the importance measures are calculated, specifically the `IncNodePurity` measure.

When I use `?importance` the  `randomForest` package states:

> The second measure (i.e., IncNodePurity) is the total decrease in node impurities
>   from splitting on the variable, averaged over all trees. For
>   classification, the node impurity is measured by the Gini index. For
>   regression, it is measured by residual sum of squares.

So, if I am interpreting it correctly, for regression, the measure is the total decrease in the residual sum of squares (RSS) after splitting on the variable.

Can anyone help me find a mathematical definition of this method, so I can help clarify this concept in my mind? I have searched quite a bit and although there are a lot of explanations on the internet, no one seems to define this method mathematically.

Would I be correct in saying that it is the difference in MSE measured both before and after a split? If the MSE is given by:

$MSE = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n(y_{i}-y_{i}^p)^2$

and $ \Delta i$ is the decrease from splitting:

$\Delta i = MSE_{before} - MSE_{after}$

The Impurity resulting from the split is recorded for all nodes (n) and all trees(T) would be given by something like:

$IMP = \sum_{T} \sum_{n} \Delta i(n,T)$

Im basing this on information I found that states that this importance measure is analogous to the Gini-index.

Some discussion relating this importance measure to MSE can be found here:
[In a random forest, is larger %IncMSE better or worse?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162465/in-a-random-forest-is-larger-incmse-better-or-worse)

and here: [Measures of variable importance in random forests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12605/measures-of-variable-importance-in-random-forests)

Comment: I wouldn't agree that my question is a duplicate because in the examples you provide, none of them give a mathematical definition of the `IncNodePurity` measure for regression.

Comment: Soren's answer in the link question is perfectly fine I think. `mse0` is the usual [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) in the context of regression. It is just the case that the measure is not renamed as `IncNodeMSE` in the case of regression but aside that everything follows in the same way. For example see: [Breiman (2001)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010933404324) in section 11 where it directly deals with MSE as the metric used for the generalisation error.

Comment: Im slightly confused... are you saying that MSE is calculated before a split and again after a split... and the difference between them is summed over all splits for that variable, over all trees?

Comment: Yes, of course. How else would we know how much better we do after a partiular split? To that extent, certain boosting algorithm that employ regression as their base learners (e.g. LightGBM) have a "minimum gain to split" attribute when training exactly so they regularise splits that might overfit.

Comment: Sorry for being explicit but would I be right in saying that the formula I give in the question is how `IncNodePurity` is calculated, except using MSE instead of RSS... and then summed over all splits and trees?

Comment: The formula provided is problematic because 1. it assumes a linear combination of features and 2. it does not distinguish between pre- and post-split. As it stands it should always be evaluate to 0. But yes, we need to account for all spits across all trees.

Comment: I've edited the question, would the method I've outlined now be more in line with what is happening?

Comment: Yes, it would be.