# Units for importance from the varimp function applied to random forest model in caret?

Tags: random-forest, importance

I am being asked what the units are for variable importance using the varimp() function for a caret package random forest model. My best answer based on previous posts is % but is that accurate? Would %MSE be a better interpretation, something else entirely or is it unitless and just showing relative magnitude? The caret documentation does not say and previous posts are not definitive on this.

Comment: you can find the answer in the following topic: [Why does random forest variable importance not sum to 100](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365955/why-does-random-forest-variable-importance-not-sum-to-100)