# Interpreting units for random forest variable importance

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, variable

I've trained a random forest for classification in R's `caret` package using the `ranger` method and impurity for measuring variable importance. I would like to figure out what the units are for the variable importance measure returned by the model. Here's what I get when I pull importance directly from the `ranger` object and sort it (i.e., `mod$finalModel$variable.importance %>% sort(decreasing=T) %>% head()`).

`diffF3F1_60    diffF3F1_65    diffF3F1_55    diffF3F1_50    diffF3F1_70    diffF3F2_70 
   127.43557      118.43874      113.98248      108.31281       97.81280       89.38337`

The help doc for `ranger` says "The 'impurity' measure is the Gini index for classification", but the Gini index has a range of [0, 1] and these importance figures are obviously out of that range. My best guess is that these figures are the summed Gini index over all splits for that variable across the forest (e.g., [Measures of variable importance in random forests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12605/measures-of-variable-importance-in-random-forests)), but I'm not totally sure. What do these numbers mean?

For what it's worth, I know that I can get these measures scaled so that the max is 100 if I use `mod %>% caret::varImp()`. However, this doesn't address the underlying question of what the raw figures are that are being scaled to 100.